# Does Flask manage matrix parameter extraction from URLs as well as ordinary parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I would like to use Flask to handle URLs of the type:

```
http://localhost/aaa/bbb/ccc;x=1;y=10;z=11/ddd/
```

where x, y, z could have sensible defaults applied if they are absent (as would be possible with ddd for example).

One possible approach is to receive all the path, then split and handle manually:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:varargs>')
def hello(varargs = None):
    if varargs:
        print varargs
    else:
        print "Hello World"
```

Is there a more graceful approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 8):

No, out of the box doesn't support such URLs.

However, Flask uses the [Werkzeug library](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) for routing, and that library supports creating [custom converters](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#custom-converters) for path elements. It should not be too hard to provide a converter. This would need to be applied to specific path elements:

```
@app.route('/aaa/bbb/ccc<matrix(x=1, y=10, z=11):matrix_params>/ddd/')
```

Note the ability to pass in arguments; here `x=1, y=10, z=11` are arguments to the converter, specifying default values for the matrix parameters.

The converter could be:

```
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter, ValidationError

class MatrixConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, **defaults):
        super(MatrixConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
        self.defaults = {k: str(v) for k, v in defaults.items()}

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value.startswith(';'):
            raise ValidationError()
        value = value[1:]
        parts = value.split(';')
        result = self.defaults.copy()
        for part in value.split(';'):
            try:
                key, value = part.split('=')
            except ValueError:
                raise ValidationError()
            result[key.strip()] = value.strip()
        return result

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ';' + ';'.join('{}={}'.format(*item) for item in value.items())
```

To add a custom converter to Flask, add it to the [`app.url_map.converters` dictionary](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.url_map):

```
app.url_map.converters['matrix'] = MatrixConverter
```

before you add any routes that rely on this converter.